# hide and show buttons in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

developers
I have this issues here with hide and show buttons.

```
    <!-- Create Folder button -->
         <li class="nav-item">
     <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="document.getElementById('createFolderForm').style.display = 'block'; return false;"> <i class="far fa-folder fa-1x"></i> Create Folder</a>


    <form id="createFolderForm" action="/create-folder" method="post" style="display: none; font-size: smaller;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <BR>
        <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="{{ $path }}">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Folder name" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    </form>
         </li>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Upload files button -->
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"  onclick="document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.display = 'block'; return false;"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Upload File</a>

    <form id="uploadForm" action="/upload" method="post" style="display: none; font-size: smaller;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <BR>
        <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="{{ $path }}">
        Select file to upload:<BR>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload" required>
        <BR><BR> <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        Encrypt
        <input type="checkbox" name="encrypt" value="1">
        <BR><BR>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    </form>
</li>
</ul>
    <br><br>
```

I've created a folder and upload file button and I wanted them to be in some sort of a nav. The problem I'm facing is that when I click on 'create folder' it'll show but when I click on 'Upload file' button it will show without hiding the information from create folder. I was trying to make it like show and hide when either one of them is clicked but failed to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Carefully think the steps through before implementing.

Comment: @TheOracle Thank you for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set another form to `display: none;` when button is clicked?

```html
<!-- Create Folder button -->
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="document.getElementById('createFolderForm').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.display = 'none'; return false;">
      <i class="far fa-folder fa-1x"></i>
      Create Folder
    </a>
    <form id="createFolderForm" action="/create-folder" method="post" style="display: none; font-size: smaller;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="{{ $path }}">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Folder name" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    </form>
  </li>

  <!-- Upload files button -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadForm').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('createFolderForm').style.display = 'none'; return false;">
      <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
      Upload File
    </a>
    <form id="uploadForm" action="/upload" method="post" style="display: none; font-size: smaller;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="{{ $path }}">
      Select file to upload:<br>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload" required>
      <br><br>
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      Encrypt
      <input type="checkbox" name="encrypt" value="1">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```